# Start workflow once Approval workflow is 'Approved'

Tags: workflow, approval

Im trying to get a workflow to start once the SharePoint Approval workflow has completed and set to 'Approved'. I cannot get this to start automatically - any help!?!

I can get it to work manually by using the command:

Wait for Approval to equal 16

then create item in List

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need 2 separate workflows. Try approval process within your workflow.

Create a new workflow in SharePoint Designer and find a following actions.

**Actions > Task Actions > Start Approval Process**

This action automatically start a approval process within your workflow. [Article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Workflow-actions-in-SharePoint-Designer-2010-A-quick-reference-guide-5a7ad276-0ed7-49b0-b652-e56a77dd96c6)

Comment: Never thought to do it this way, thankyou!